# Как скомпилировать проект pycharm в exe форму?

Tags: python, pyqt5, exe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть три py файла:

functions - отвечает за список функций

name - в нем располагаются данные о форме из main.ui

test - в котором реализуются функции из functions, ну и соответственно логика приложения (что происходит при нажатии на кнопку, какая кнопка за что отвечает итд)

Теперь к сути, какой алгоритм я должен проделать, чтобы получить полноценный exe файл с рабочей формой?
Использовал pyinstaller name.py, но получил лишь форму, в которой не работают кнопки и все остальное. 
Буду благодарен за полезные ответы.

Comment: Вам надо опубликовать минимальный пример, чтобы желающие могли попробовать и что-то вам сказать.

Comment: @S.Nick https://ibb.co/BtwyP44 Вот мои 3 файла в одном проекте, чуть ниже представлена часть формы
Форма зависит от всех 3 файлов, test подгружает name и functions и является самой основной (если так можно выразиться)